# Inner derivations determined by idempotent elements and nilpotent elements

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

If R is a prime ring, $e\in R$ is a non-central idempotent and $d$ is an inner derivation determined 
 by $e$, then $0\neq d=d^{3}=d^{5}...$  
 If $b\in R$ is a non-central nilpotent element of a degree $n$ and $d$ is an inner derivation determined by $b$,then $d^{2n-1}=0$,although $d \neq0$ 
How can we show above examples ?

Comment: FFR: choose titles that accurately reflect your question. The original title "noncommutative prime ring" seemed to have no connection at all with your question, although that may be the context you encountered it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a feel for the pattern:

$$bx-xb \\
b^2x-2bxb+xb^2\\
b^3x-3b^2xb+3bxb^2-xb^3$$

By this point, the formula $d^n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}b^{n-i}xb^{i}$ suggests itself. Prove it using induction.

You see that in order for all terms to hit zero, a power of b in every term has to hit n. $2n$ certainly works, but you can further show that $2n-1$ is sufficient.

If b is idempotent, we see the third line cancels down to the first, hence $d^3=d$, and by induction $d^{2n+1}=d$.

Finally, I hope you already see that an element is central iff its derivation is zero.

Comment: Thank you so much rschwieb

Comment: rschwieb I  have more one question.R prime ring Z non-trivial center.Then what is the meaning of Z-linear derivation :?

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 To me, Z linear means $d(zx)=zd(x)$ for all z in Z. I don't often work with derivations so I cannot guarantee this.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 It's clear that inner derivations are $Z$ linear in the sense I suggested.

Comment: thanks you.Congratulate on your academic life.

Comment: $Z$ linear means $d(zx)=zd(x)$ for all z in $Z$.This is true .So we can say $d(zx)=d(z)x+zd(x)=zd(x)$, Hence we can  say $d(z)x=0$, can't?

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 Yes, I hadn't considered it, but that is a second way to prove it. You have $d(z)=0$ for any inner derivation $d$ and central element $z$, and it follows that $d(zx)=zd(x)$ from the Leibniz law, so that is a second way to prove inner derivations are $Z$ linear. I just proved it in the straightforward way: $d(zx)=bzx-zxb=z(bx-xb)=zd(x)$.